# Woocommerce how to show shipping fields

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building an ecommerce website in wordpress, with woocommerce plugin.
When I go to the checkout page only the billing fields are showing, the shipping address fields are not visible (only showing Additional information field)

I'm using the latest version of Woocommerce (2.6.6); what can I do to show those shipping fields?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have at least one zone and one shipping method setup, otherwise no shipping options (or shipping address fields) will show.

Answer (score 1):

It is configurable.

In WooCommerce->Settings->Shipping Tab, find shipping options and make sure the Shipping Destination is set to 'Default to customer billing address' or 'Default to customer shipping address'.

If it is set to 'Force shipping to the customer billing address', the shipping fields will not be displayed.

Comment: Can't see Shipping Tab at all. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @CidaoPapito which woocommerce version did you use?

Answer (score 1):

**Add a shipping zone**
Go to woocommerce > settings > shipping > add shipping zone

Comment: Can't see Shipping Tab at all. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/12l8wbo88q44zxh/Screenshot_3.png

See my screenshot. If you do not see any shipping tab then it might be a installation problem. Make backup of database, uninstall woocommerce then install it again

Answer (score 1):

If the WooCommerce->Settings->Shipping Tab is not visible, make sure that WooCommerce->Settings->General->Shipping location(s) is *not* set to "Disable shipping & shipping calculations".

Answer (score 0):

That's odd! The shipping tab should be visible and accessible to you after the installation is done. I can only guess that your installation process might have gone wrong somewhere or there's a problem with your DB. Did you try re-doing the entire process again?

If you're still facing the issue then you should contact WooCommerce directly, they should help you out. And like others have said, you should also re-check your shipping zone and shipping destination as well(maybe this guide could help you with that: https://www.pluginhive.com/woocommerce-shipping-a-complete-tutorial/).

That's my two cents! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be that your products are set as "virtual" make sure you have these boxes unchecked.

Products -> [your product] all the way at the bottom.

[image: Product data]